# does installing xubuntu-desktop cause instability?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, gui, desktop-environments, window-manager

After a clean install of 20.04 to older hardware I installed both xfce4 and xubuntu-desktop and then removed ubuntu-desktop.

Will this cause instability?

Comment: No, did see any issues with XUbuntu?

Comment: frankly, it seems completely unchanged.  I think the desktop background is different, but that's it.

Comment: No, I can't see why not. Your question I suspect though is very opinion oriented, and thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I only asked because on IRC they were saying that installing xubuntu-desktop would cause instabaility.

Comment: You wrote, that its unchanged... that's not true, did you select xfce before the login?

Comment: I can see the discussion on IRC, and I'd trust *lotuspsychje*, however we all have different experiences. If I removed `ubuntu-desktop`, before I accepted the removal (ie. I'd never use a `-y` in the removal, and read the output of what will be removed), I'd note anything that I did need for my remaining system and re-install that. I'm convinced it won't cause instability, but I'd also read the output of removed packages & adjust according to what I saw.  I've not done this with *focal*, but have other releases thus my 2c

Comment: If done properly, there should be no instability. However, you did not show us the apt output, so we cannot say that you did it properly. Debian packages use external dependencies and idempotence precisely to keep systems stable under a wide range of conditions...but are not magical.

Comment: FYI:  If you want to know the effects before you try something, setup a VM and try it there. VMs are quick & easy; I usually do it on real hardware & real installs, but I QA test and so usually have a system I can use & know a system will be cleanly re-installed in a day or two anyway (making that faster than a VM usually). We all have different definitions of old-hardware, but that plays no part either.

Comment: good point @SimonSudler -- I'll look into how to select xubuntu.  I was more concerned about instability.