# how to select xubuntu-desktop?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, gui, desktop-environments, window-manager

Having [installed](https://askubuntu.com/q/1270230/847449) `xubuntu-desktop` how do I now select it for use?

I'm not [seeing](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-xubuntu-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) an option to select:

[image: 18.x]

I'm running 20.04, so [perhaps](https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/ubuntu-xubuntu.html) it's different from the above image.  Everything seems exactly the same (although the desktop image was changed).

Comment: It's the *Xubuntu Session* on that image.

Comment: After you added `xubuntu-desktop`, did you restart `gdm3` or your DM/greeter?  The option may not show until that is done (or you reboot).

Comment: After you login via the "Xubuntu Session" open a terminal and type `ls /usr/bin/*session` and let us know what the output is. It will show what you have installed.

Comment: yes, after reboot everything looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reinstall the related packages by:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-default-settings xfce4-session
```

Then reboot and locate Xubuntu of Xfce session on GDM login screen.

Also I would recommend to reinstall full Xubuntu task package by:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop^
```